# How to align div horizontally in a row using Bootstrap

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

I am trying to divide a page into two parts i.e. 6 + 6 columns and put 3 divs horizontally in each part. Divs exceeding 3 align in bottom row in same part of page.

I am trying but still not able to align correctly. Here is my code. How can I do this?

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="row" id="meta-search">

  <div class="col-sm-6">
    <h5> IDs </h5>
    <form action="" method="post">

      <div class="col-sm-2 mb-3">
        <label>ID1</label>
        <input type="number" class="form-control">
      </div>

      <div class="col-sm-2 mb-3">
        <label>ID2</label>
        <input type="number" class="form-control">
      </div>

      <div class="col-sm-2 mb-3">
        <label>ID3</label>
        <input type="number" class="form-control">
      </div>

      <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" name="submit1" type="submit">Search Record</button>

    </form>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Each element is relative to the parent; a col-sm-6 will be 50%, but the col-sm-2 inside it will be approx. 16% of the 50%, or 8% of the total width.

Comment: But these are not aligning horizontally but vertically. 16+16+16 = 48, so a 4th one with this ratio should go into next row. But this is not happening. This is how I am thinking.

Comment: Take a look at this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/6d09q3ru/ --- in bootstrap 4, simply calling the "col" class will give elements the same widths,; they must however be in a row.

Comment: yes `col` does automatic width calculations and fits accordingly, recently came around it, when I had to make 5 cols within a row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing  another  inside the  tag.
Just add this

```
  <form action="" method="post"> 
   <div class="row">
```

Answer (score 1):

the class `col` in bootstrap does it, you need to add a `row` class div for it, within the row you put the `col` divs, bootstrap calculates the width accordingly depending on number of cols you put within `row` div.

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="row" id="meta-search">

  <div class="col-sm-6">
    <h5> IDs </h5>
    <form action="" method="post">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col mb-3">
          <label>ID1</label>
          <input type="number" class="form-control">
        </div>

        <div class="col mb-3">
          <label>ID2</label>
          <input type="number" class="form-control">
        </div>

        <div class="col mb-3">
          <label>ID3</label>
          <input type="number" class="form-control">
        </div>
      </div>
      <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" name="submit1" type="submit">Search Record</button>

    </form>
  </div>

</div>
```